# Django: Ajas and Reverse error: "str" object is not callable

Tags: ajax, django

I have some code that will return to an ajax call a reverse-url that is defined in my urls.py I have the user update a page and then they click submit. When they click submit they should return to the item list view instead of the item update view.

Views.py

This returns the same page successfully, but it isn't what I want.

```
return JsonResponse({"status": "success",
        "message": message})
```

This produces an error message `"next_url": reverse("item:list"), TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

```
return JsonResponse({"status": "success",
        "next_url": reverse("item:list"), 
        "message": message})
```

HTML page

Here is the template's ajax used to route the user:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/item/ajax/approve/',
    data: {
      'reply': reply,
      'item': item,
      'user_type': userType,
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var successMsg = data.message 
        if (data.status){
            successMsg = successMsg + "<br/><br/><i class='fa fa-spin fa-spinner'></i> Redirecting..." //<i class> - 'font awesome'
        }

        if (data.next_url){
            if ($.alert){  // if alert message is installed
            $.alert(successMsg)
            } else {
                alert("")
            }
            redirectToNext(data.next_url, 1500)  
        } else {
            location.reload();
        }


    }
  });
```

Comment: Post whole error message with full traceback and your `urls.py` please

Comment: try to use `reverse_lazy("item:list")`.

Comment: reverse_lazy worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `reverse` function in the beginning of your file.

`from django.urls import reverse`

Comment: I was already importing reverse. Another person suggested reverse_lazy and that worked! Thanks for your suggestion.